# Debian Jessie FSTAB Automount network problem

Tags: fstab, automounting

Ok I made a reinstallation of my **Debian 8 Jessie** last night and my home Directory wasn't erased (don't know if any confs might interfere on this).

So I have a **Network CIFS** share I want to **Automount**. Everything is configured on the server side (I was able to do this connection two days ago and nothing changed on the server side)

Ok So I don't remember what configuration was the one I made in my `/etc/fstab` before when it was working, but I'm trying all guides on the net and I can't seem to find a solution to mount this at startup.

Here is my FSTAB conf:

```
//192.168.1.105/Media      /media/xxxxxx/Media     cifs     user,auto,username=xxxxxxx,password=xxxxxxx     0     0
```

I've changed every sensitive info with an "X" here for obvious reasons but the path and login data match the servers!

I've tried creating a credential file as well but I remember last time it worked it was with these configurations. I want to be able to unmount at anytime that's why I'm putting `user` on the line here.

My outputs are different depending the configuration. Right now, with this conf, I get this output:

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Oh my network CIFS share has this particular share with **NTFS**, don't know if counts.

Don't remember if last time I added a Mask or an ID or Filetype or any other configuration that made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I did some tests and aparently two things made it work.

1. I've changed the IP to the name of the machine (media.local in my case)
2. Added `File_mode` and `Dir_mode` to it

Here what became of my `/etc/fstab` config line:

```
//media.local/Media     /media/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/Media     cifs     defaults,user,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,auto,username=xxxxxxxx,password=xxxxxxx     0     0
```

I don't know why it worked with the name of the machine instead of the IP or why the `File_Mode` and `File_Dir` made a difference... But there you go... That was the solution!